# Change state depending on holidays, weekends or hour of day

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm writing a script that's changing the background color depending on hour of day, if it is a weekend or if it is a Swedish holiday. I have a functional script and as I want to improve my programming skills I want to see if there's anything I can do differently or more efficiently.

I wanted to work with separate functions to (hopefully) improve readability and make the script more adaptable by passing parameters. The script also runs a function on an interval to update the background color if the allowed time span has been passed. My concern is that this will affect performance as far as I know it will not be too CPU intensive.

```js
 closedDates();

 function closedDates() {
  //Create new date object
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getFullYear();

  var closedDates = (calculateClosedDates(year));

  var closedDates = [
   new Date(year, 0, 1),   // Fixed date: New Years day
   new Date(year, 0, 5),   // Fixed date: Twelfth Night
   new Date(year, 0, 6),   // Fixed date: Epiphany
   new Date(closedDates[0]), // Thursday
   new Date(closedDates[1]),  // Good Friday
   new Date(closedDates[2]),  // Easter Day
   new Date(closedDates[3]),  // Easter Monday
   new Date(year, 3, 30),   // Fixed date: Walpurgis Night
   new Date(year, 4, 1),  // Fixed date: International Workers' Day
   new Date(closedDates[4]), // Feast of the Ascension
   new Date(closedDates[5]), // Pingstafton
   new Date(closedDates[6]), // Pingstdagen
   new Date(year, 5, 6),   // Fixed date: Swedish National Day
   new Date(closedDates[7]), // Saint John's Eve
   new Date(closedDates[8]), // Midsummer day
   new Date(closedDates[9]), // All Saints' Eve
   new Date(closedDates[10]), // All Saints' Day
   new Date(year, 11, 24),  // Fixed date: Christmas Eve
   new Date(year, 11, 25),  // Fixed date: Christmas Day
   new Date(year, 11, 26),  // Fixed date: Christmas Eve
   new Date(year, 11, 31)  // Fixed date: New Years Eve
  ];

  // Pass current date and date array to function
  checkDate(d, closedDates);
 }

 function checkDate(d, closedDates) {

  var openingHour = 10,
   closingHour = 18,
   weekend = [0, 6];

  // Run check time once to see if it is open
  checkTime();

  // Check if time falls in between time span and is not a weekend
  // Change background color if/else
  function checkTime() {
   d = new Date()
   console.log(d);
   if (d.getHours() < openingHour || d.getHours() >= closingHour || d.getDay() === weekend[0] || d.getDay() === weekend[1]) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
   else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
   }
  }
  // Check if current date is equal to a date in the date array
  // Converting to time to be able to compare
  // Change background colour accordingly
  for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
   if (d.getTime() === closedDates[i].getTime()) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return
   }
   else {
    // Run script in 30 second intervals to update background reguraly
    setInterval(checkTime, 30000);
    return
   }
  } 

 }

 function calculateClosedDates(year) {
  /* This function calculates and returns an array with date objects of Swedish public holidays
     Many days are based on when easterDay occurs and therefore I use
     Gauss Easter Algorithm to calculate when easter day occurs for the current year.

     It uses constanst M & N that needs to be updated 2099 but this is a non issue.
     I could include a function that checks which year it is and updates the constants
     accordingly but I feel it's over ambitious for this script. 

     Some days are fixed dates and some holidays shift and therefore need to be calculated 
  */

  // Start Gauss Easter Algorithm
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Gauss's_Easter_algorithm

  // Constants, update year 2099 ;)

  var M = 24,
   N = 5,

   a = year % 19,
   b = year % 4,
   c = year % 7,

   d = ((19*a) + M) % 30,
   e = ((2*b) + (4*c) + (6*d) + N) % 7,

   easterDay = 22 + d + e,

  // Easter Month as default March
   easterMonth = 2;

  // If easterDay is greater than 31, take value minus 31
  // Set month to April
  if (easterDay > 31) {
   easterDay = easterDay - 31;
   easterMonth = 3;
  }

  // Exceptions to formula

  // If easterDay is 26 and easterMonth is April
  // set date a week earlier
  if (easterDay == 26 && easterMonth == 4) {
   easterDay = easterDay - 7;
  }

  // If easterDay is 25, easterMonth is April, d is 28, e is 6 and a is greater than 10
  // set date a week earlier
  if (easterDay == 25 && easterMonth == 4 && d == 28 && e == 6 && a > 10) {
   easterDay = easterDay - 7;
  }
  // End Gauss Easter Formula

  var maundyThursday  = new Date(year, easterMonth, easterDay-3),    // Will always occur on the first thursday before easter day
   goodFriday   = new Date(year, easterMonth, easterDay-2),    // Will always occur on the first friday before easter day
   easter    = new Date(year, easterMonth, easterDay),    // Value from Gauss
   easterMonday  = new Date(year, easterMonth, easterDay+1),    // Will always occur on the first monday after easter day
   ascension   = new Date(year, easterMonth, ((easterDay+4) + 35)),  // Get the next thursday from easter day + 35 days (5 weeks)
   pingstAfton  = new Date(year, easterMonth, easterDay+48),   // 7 Weeks - 1 day after easter day
   pingstDagen  = new Date(year, easterMonth, easterDay+49),   // 7 Weeks after easter day 
   midsommarAfton  = getSpecificDay(5, new Date(year, 5, 20)),    // From start date, find first friday
   midsommarDagen  = getSpecificDay(6, new Date(year, 5, 20)),    // From start date, find first saturday
   allSaintsEve  = getSpecificDay(5, new Date(year, 9, 30)),    // From start date, find first friday
   allSaintsDay  = getSpecificDay(6, new Date(year, 9, 31));    // From start date, find first saturday

  function getSpecificDay(holiday, startDate) {
   // Get which specific day that the holiday (friday, saturday) is and then get the start date of the period 
   var calculatedDate = startDate;
   calculatedDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (holiday - startDate.getDay() % 7));

   return calculatedDate;
  }
                  
  return [maundyThursday, goodFriday, easter, easterMonday, ascension, pingstAfton, pingstDagen, midsommarAfton, midsommarDagen, allSaintsEve, allSaintsDay];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions..

- The Easter day calculation should [be in its own function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
- I would probably put this as a single one liner arrow function (and move it up a few lines) `const getSpecificDay = (h, s) => s.setDate(s.getDate() + (h - s.getDay() % 7));`. That just looks cleaner IMO.
- You should combine `closedDates()` and `calculateClosedDates()` since they're basically both doing the same thing.

Instead of checking the hour every 30 seconds, you're better off calculating the number of milliseconds until the next hour and start checking at that time every hour.

```
var d = new Date()
d.setHours(d.getHours()+1, 0, 0, 0)
var nextHour = d.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

setTimeout(()=>{
    checkTime();
    setInterval(checkTime, 60*60*1000);
}, nextHour);
```

Aside from a few formatting things it looks pretty good man.

Answer (score 0):

## Never mix information and code

I have a fundamental problem with your code.

### Existing data

The calculations for Easter dates looks complex, too complex to trust there are not typos or errors in the code. It would be dangerous to release this service without first testing it over the period you expect this application to provide its service. Hence you should already have a list of Easter holiday dates available to do the test.

Why complicate when you have that data at hand already?

### Changing information should not mean changing code

As nothing is set in stone and thus it is highly likely that you will need to make changes to things like open and close times, add exceptions to weekends, amend public holiday times. As you have hard coded all possible information that is subject to possible change changes will require a programmer, and a full test cycle.

Changes cost time and money, and if you don't have a good contract, that cost may be yours to bear, or worse that time may come when you have none to spare.

### Deligate responsibility

- You are a coder, you write code.
- The trader runs a trade, manages opening times and does not write code.
- Many people set holidays, they provide services regarding this information

I would highly stress that this type of service (calculating trading hours) be up to the client (the trader) and that you (the coder) provide an interface (server based) for the client to make changes as needed.

That you outsource the calculation of holidays to an API (Example. Randomly selected [Holiday API](https://holidayapi.com/) from a google search)

You do not get involved in changing holidays, and trading hours, you provide the means for those that do to provide the information that your code needs to change the background color.

### Rewriting your app

The rewrite is an example only, untested, and data copied and unverified.
Holidays, trading times and days are as separate data objects that could be delivered as JSON. They are required for the code to load.

To simplify holiday checks, dates are converted to days of the year.

Now your timed function need only do the following.

```
document.body.classList[tradingInfo.isClosed ? "add" : "remove"]("bg-color--trading-closed");
```

#### The code

```
//=============================================
// Helpers and conversion code
const msInHour = 100 * 60 * 60;    
const msInDay = msInHour * 24;
const tradingTimeZone = 8 * msInHour;
const weekDays = {sun: 0, mon: 1, tue: 2, wed: 3, thu: 4, fri: 5, sat: 6}
const dayOfYearFromDate = date => (date.valueOf() + tradingTimeZone) / msInDay | 0;
const dayOfYear = (year, month, day) => dayOfYearFromDate(new Date(year, month, day));
const dayOfYearOfWeekDayNear = (year, weekDayNameShort, month, date) => {
    const dt = new Date(year, month, date);
    return dayOfYearFromDate(
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (weekDays[weekDayNameShort] - dt.getDay() % 7))
    );
}
const holidaysDayOfYear = (year) => holidays.map(monthDay => dayOfYear(year,...monthDay));
const easterHolidays = (year) => {
    const day = dayOfYear(year, ...easterInfo[year]);
    return [
        ...easterInfo.offsetDays.map(offset => day + offset),
        ...easterInfo.weekDayNear.map(dayNear => dayOfYearOfWeekDayNear(year,...dayNear)),
    ];
}

/* Requires holiday info and trading data  before this can be run and used */

// the object that converts data to isClosed 
const tradingInfo = {
    closed {
        hours: weeklyTradingClosed.hours, // 24hr ranges [from, to]
        days: weeklyTradingClosed.daysOfWeek, // index from 0 sun to 6 sat
        holidays : [ // array of days of the year
            ...easterHolidays(new Date().getFullYear()), 
            ...holidaysDayOfYear(new Date().getFullYear())
        ], 
    },
    get isClosed() {
        const date = new Date();
        const hour = date.getHour();
        const dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
        const dayOfYear = dayOfYearFromDate(date);
        return tradingInfo.closed.hour.some(hours => hour >= hours[0] &&  hour <= hours[1]) ||
            tradingInfo.closed.days.some(day => day = dayOfWeek) || 
            tradingInfo.closed.holidays.includes(dayOfYear);
    },     
};
```

#### Information required

```
// sources
// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211317/120556
const weeklyTradingClosed = {hours : [[0, 10], [18, 24]], daysOfWeek : [0,6]}
const holidays = [
    [0, 1],     // New Years day
    [0, 5],     // Twelfth Night
    [0, 6],     // Epiphany
    [3, 30],    // Walpurgis Night
    [4, 1],     // International Workers' Day
    [5, 6],     // Swedish National Day
    [11, 24],   // Christmas Eve
    [11, 25],   // Christmas Day
    [11, 26],   // Christmas Eve
    [11, 31],   // New Years Eve
};
```

#### Easter info for next 20 years

You don't need a complicated formula, we know the dates already, use that information.

```
// sources
// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211317/120556
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dates_for_Easter  Using western dates.
const easterInfo = { 
    offsetDays : [-3, -2, 0, 1, 39, 48, 49],   
    weekdayNear : [["fri", 5, 20], ["sat", 5, 20], ["fri", 9, 30], ["sat", 9, 31]],
    "2019": [3, 21],
    "2020": [3, 12],
    "2021": [3, 4],
    "2022": [3, 17],
    "2023": [3, 9],
    "2024": [2, 31],
    "2025": [3, 20],
    "2026": [3, 5,],
    "2027": [2, 28],
    "2028": [3, 16],
    "2029": [3, 1],
    "2030": [3, 21],
    "2031": [3, 13],
    "2032": [2, 28],
    "2033": [3, 17],
    "2034": [3, 9],
    "2035": [2, 25],
    "2036": [3, 13],
    "2037": [3, 5],
    "2038": [3, 2],
    "2039": [3, 1],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Remove UI code**

```
if (d.getHours() < openingHour || d.getHours() >= closingHour || d.getDay() === weekend[0] || d.getDay() === weekend[1]) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
```

Mixing UI code with what should be pure holiday calculation code is the worse thing I see for the long term health of your application. Instead client code (the UI)  should call an object method or property but shall not return a color because that's UI business.

Think about it - why would my calculator assume anything about why I'm doing a calculation or how I will use it. When the calculation output is "green" instead of true or false (is what I suspect you want) then that calculator is now useless for anything except that exact, lone thing. The code is not reusable.

---

**The comments** read the literal code. You should assume the reader knows how to read code and then have comments that tell "why" or "what."  Kudos for referencing the algorithm source.

Bad comments:

```
//Create new date object
var d = new Date();
. . .
// If easterDay is greater than 31, take value minus 31
// Set month to April
if (easterDay > 31) {
   easterDay = easterDay - 31;
   easterMonth = 3;
}
. . .
// Pass current date and date array to function
checkDate(d, closedDates);
```

OK comments:

```
// Exceptions to formula
. . .
// Run check time once to see if it is open
    checkTime();
```

---

Should be unnecessary comments:

```
// Easter Month as default March
        easterMonth = 2;
```

Define constants for the months

---

Make `closedDates` an object then you don't have to memorize the order in the array and induce coding errors.

```
var closedDates = [
        new Date(year, 0, 1),       // Fixed date: New Years day
        new Date(year, 0, 5),       // Fixed date: Twelfth Night
        new Date(year, 0, 6),       // Fixed date: Epiphany
        new Date(closedDates[0]),   // Thursday

var closedDates = {
        "NewYears" : new Date(year, 0, 1),
        "TwelfthNight" : new Date(year, 0, 5),
        "Epiphany" : new Date(year, 0, 6),
        "Thursday" : new Date(closedDates[0]),
```

A weekday should not be in the holidays structure. Make a 'weekdays' structure instead. If you meant 'maundyThursday' I suspect that making an object in the first place would have avoided the commenting error.

---

**Naming**

Name things to reflect the subject domain not the code implementation details. Sometimes (often?) unnecessary comments - see above - can suggest appropriate names.

`closedDates` are not dates, they are holidays.  And does it really matter to the `closedDates` user if they are closed or not? Anyway `closedDates` also includes open dates and  so the name is more wrong. What does open and closed mean anyway?

Making day & month constants will make the whole thing far more understandable, significantly prevent errors, and otherwise unnecessary comments.

Rethink all the function names. For example `checkDate` is meaningless. I know how hard that is; 30 character names is no so good either so sometimes you just have to settle for good function comments.

Comment: -1 I can not agree with your advice on naming dates. All the code needs do is change the background color depending on the current time and date. Introducing named dates adds a completely unrelated abstraction to the code. . The time and dates do not need to be ordered, the OP's error was to index directly rather than add easter holidays using `...` operator  eg `const  closedDates = [ ...calculateClosedDates(year), new Date(year, 0, 1), ` and so on.

Comment: *All the code needs do is change the background color depending on the current time and date*   But it does two things, calculate the holidays and updates the UI. There is a separation of concerns here - a single responsibility principle problem.

Comment: *Introducing named dates adds a completely unrelated abstraction*   How can naming dates as the holidays they are be unrelated to dates that are these holidays?

Comment: *the OP's error was to index directly rather than add easter holidays using ... operator ...*  The spread operator may be concise, etc. but not using it is not "an error." More to the point, this all utterly misses the point. Client code can reference the holidays by their names rather than an index position in an array. As written these positions cannot change - holidays cannot be added or removed without breaking this code and any client code.

Comment: "...but not using it is not "an error."" I was referring to the comment error you used to justify naming the dates "...would have avoided the commenting error."

Comment: Down votes should be explained. It helps everyone. **down vote criteria**:  *Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.*

Comment: Downvotes do not require explanation. Why would they be anonymous if they required explanation? But the point is mute as I have given you the reason for the down vote.